# JSch SSH Connection not Logging user log in to Server

Tags: unix, ssh, aix, jsch

I have a list of servers which I have access to which I need to log in at least once every 30 days in order to maintain my access so for my first program using JSch, I wanted to create a program that will take in a list of hosts, a username and password and log me in and out each sever.

I'm able to connect fine to the servers and even execute commands but if I run the Unix command "last " it doesn't show that I had logged into the server. Any insight as to why it doesn't log when I run the program but it logs if I log in using putty would be greatly appreciated.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(userId, host, port);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.connect(timeout);

Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
channel.connect();

InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
        int readByte = commandOutput.read();
while(readByte != 0xffffffff)
{
  outputBuffer.append((char)readByte);
  readByte = commandOutput.read();
}

channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that if you allocate a pseudo-terminal,

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);      // !!!!
channel.connect();
```

you will find it in command "last" , but you may get unnecessary character sequences for the terminal emulator from its input stream.  How about checking /var/log/secure, /var/log/auth.log rather than doing in the outputs from last command?

And then, it will be better to invoke Channel#getInputStream() before Channel#connect(),
because some data received during Channel#connect() and Channel#getInputStream() may be lost.